# Playing DASH streaming video from a DRM protected app inside another app without the decryption key

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I need to play a video streaming in an on OTT platform app inside a VR application. Similar to how Netflix presents an environment VR Video player. 
This is the link to one of such apps for reference: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tv.v18.viola&hl=en

So basically this app uses DASH streaming for their video
and it is DRM encrypted

We need to provide a VR plugin to this app but we wont get the key to their encryption we need to figure out some other way to play their video directly on our plugin. So i need to know how you can do that can you run the app window inside the VR environment or maybe stream the particular video from their website into the VR environment. http://www.voot.com/# is the website link.

Any inputs on the way to implement this are welcome.

Comment: This might be interesting for you, if you have not seen it already: http://techblog.netflix.com/2015/09/john-carmack-on-developing-netflix-app.html

Answer (score 2):

The role of DRM is to protect against all unauthorized use. If a solution to this exists, it's very poor DRM. DRM does not just protect decoding. It protects access to the pixel buffer and rendering stages (HDCP). You need access to the pixel buffer to render it to a 3D surface.  If the DRM allowed for that, you could just write the pixel buffer to disk. Thus defeating the DRM. If you need alternate rendering, you need to speak to the DRM vendor.

Comment: Alright. So this is about accessing the media feed directly. What about playing the app inside another app. Basically playing the full screen video inside a Google cardboard VR environment.

Comment: No, it's about accessing the pixel buffer. DRM ensures zero access to the image pre display.

Comment: Okay. What about accessing it post display. What I am trying to say is . Is it possible to play the app itself. Inside another app

Comment: By display, I meant 'The display' e.g' Monitor/LCD. Post display it is photons. You will need a CCD to capture those. If the 'other app' requires the ability to modify the image in any way at all, inducing rotating the image, any decent DRM will not allow it, as modifying the image requires access to the image.

Comment: wow great answer! I didn't know that DRM also secures access to the pixel buffer. Can you suggest some literature to read about this in a litte bit more detail? It's kind of interesting :)